# Is possible to retrive these information from a server with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm tring to develop an API that should save many information as possible from the client to check the identity of the request.
Now I'm blocking on this information because it seem that are sent only from the client and not retrieve directly from my app.

Screen Resolution
Color Depth
Number of Colors
Window Size
JavaScript Version
Plugin Support

I found all these information here:
http://www.ip-adress.com/what_is_my_ip/
and its seem all correct so they can do that but it depend from the webclient or from the server api?

Comment: `window.screen` object has some of that info ... look at the source code of that page to see how the plugins are detected (hint: `detectPlugin` ) - look at http://www.ip-adress.com/brwsniff.js for other stuff

Comment: short answer:  **no** your server can't detect the capabilities of the clients requesting data from your API.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Jaromanda for your hints!

Comment: You can try to use this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/clientjs. It seems to get most information you need, but you have to add a `.js` in you client side as well. Good luck.

Comment: @Tom do you think thatI could a fast redirection to force to load this script if the calling came from a "non supported" client? Or it could be  a bad idea?

Comment: @tom : thank you very much but I have a new question, could I create a fast redirection to an hidden page to launch this script if the client's request come from a "non supported" client? Or it is a bad idea? (P.S.: if you answer to my question I will accept your answer...